# How to resize columns in QTreeWidget to the minimum space required

Tags: c++, qt, header, qtreewidget

I am a student programmer and I am using Qt to build a GUI interface for work. I have a `QTreeWidget` that has a total of 8 Columns. The input that needs to be entered into each one of these columns is fairly small. In that regard, I was trying to find a way to re-size all of the columns to the least amount of space required. much like the action that is performed when you click on the dividers. I have looked over several websites and the Qt documentation and haven't found a solution. After looking over the documentation it seems that there are a bunch of ways to do this but I cant get one to work. I am beginning to think that I need to enable/disable something somewhere. It's as if the changes I write in to my build function (This function clears the table; Reads data from my vector, displays certain data in the table, and then is suppose to re-size the headers/columns to just enough size to fit the contents of the column) are not even applied. I have tried the following with no changes:

```
        ui->treeWidgetInjections->setColumnWidth(i, minimumWidth());
        ui->treeWidgetInjections->resizeColumnToContents(i);
        ui->treeWidgetInjections->header()->ResizeToContents;
        ui->treeWidgetInjections->header()->resizeSection(i, minimumWidth());
```

All of these are in the end of of my build Function (unrelated info removed):

```
ui->treeWidgetInjections->clear();
    for (int i=0; i < qTreeInjectionData.size(); i++)
        {
            //fill Qtree with items;
            //fill QTree items with data;
            //re size function here;
        }
```

Please only leave productive feedback as I am only interested in learning and overcoming this challenge. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that my for loop is the issue here; in particular I think that .size might have been responsible for this issue.

Comment: I want to make first column of qtreewidget less than 20px, but It is never less than some width like 80px or 90px. How can I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This minimal example works for me:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget());
    QTreeWidget *tree = new QTreeWidget(this);
    layout->addWidget(tree);

    tree->setColumnCount(3);

    QStringList first, second, third;
    first  << "xxxxxxxxx"      << "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"     << "xxxxxxxx";
    second << "xxxxx"          << "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" << "xxxxx";
    third  << "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" << "xxxxxxxxxx"        << "xxxxxxxx";

    tree->insertTopLevelItem(0, new QTreeWidgetItem(first));
    tree->insertTopLevelItem(0, new QTreeWidgetItem(second));
    tree->insertTopLevelItem(0, new QTreeWidgetItem(third));

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        tree->resizeColumnToContents(i);
}
```

All you need to do is call the `resizeColumnToContents()` method once for every column after you populate the view. Let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Its really strange but when I created a separate for loop in my build function for my column re-sizes it worked fine... very strange. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP! Your example helped me in a big way and I am sure this will help others!

Comment: Unfortunately, This method only resize according to the contents of the header for me. Data displayed word-wrapped.

Comment: make sure it's `resizeColumnToContents` not `resizeColumn[S]ToContents`

Comment: @HareenLaks same here, the answers here have not helped me. Have you found a way?

Answer (score 20):

The problem for me was that `StretchLastSection` was set to true and if this value is set to true, this property will override the resize mode set on the last section in the header.

Solution:

```
_treeWidget = new UIWidgetSceneTree();
_treeWidget->header()->setStretchLastSection(false);
_treeWidget->header()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Comment: I prefer this way to resize, instead of defining column number one by one.

Comment: What is a `UIWidgetSceneTree`? Is it your custom subclass of `QTreeView`? It makes this answer a bit confusing.

Comment: I do not know why, but view->resizeColumnToContents(0); did not help on my QTreeView, whilst view->header()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents); The problem with this solution though is that the user can no longer resize the header. I feel like that is very limiting.